# Is it possible to add resize handler to existing widget?

Tags: jquery, resize, flot, gridster

The gridster initialization has been abstracted away from me.  Unfortunately, my content contains a Canvas plot (using Flot, if it matters) so it gets very ugly when the Gridster widget gets resized.

I can get hold of the Gridster object (via a JQuery selector), but I can't seem add a resize listener, since my Gridster widget has already been initialized.

JQuery UI's .resize() seems to be ignoring me, so I think the event isn't propagated?  Or maybe it uses a different event type?

Short of re-initializing the whole Gridster Resizeable object, is the a way to bind a resize handler?

Comment: Gridster has a demo on adding a resize callback: http://gridster.net/demos/using-resize-callbacks.html  Why can't you use this?

Comment: @Mark  Because that demo sets up the callbacks when gridster is initialized.  I'm looking to do so after the fact, since by the time my code is loaded, this has already happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to define the callback after initialization you can do it in the options property:

```
var myGrid = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
myGrid.options.resize.resize = function(){
   // do something awesome here
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this, thanks! Quick FYI though, this does throw a syntax error. The function should be closed with `}`, not `})`